# XSLT: Ignore duplicates similar values

Tags: xml, xslt

I am working on XSLT which has a logic to ignore duplicates using `(MySegment/*[not(.=preceding::*)]).`

Input:

```
<MySegment>
  <Field1>ABCD</Field1>
  <FIeld2>1</Field2>
</MySegment>
<MySegment>
  <Field1>ABCD123</Field1>
  <FIeld2>1</Field2>
</MySegment>
```

Here we have two distinct values, however since ABCD123 contains ABCD as well,its being treated as a duplicate entry. Can anyone advise.

Here is how my XSLT looks like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/RecordsInp">

    <xsl:for-each select="ParentSegment">

      <xsl:for-each select="./MySegment/*[not(.=preceding::*)]">

        <A>
          <Field1><xsl:value-of select ="name(.)"/></Field1>
          <Field2><xsl:value-of select="."/></Field2>
        </A>

      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My input is:

```
<RecordsInp>
  <ParentSegment>
    <MySegment>
      <Field1>ABC</Field1>
      <Field2>A1</Field2>
    </MySegment>

    <MySegment>
      <Field1>ABC</Field1>
      <Field2>A1</Field2>
    </MySegment>

    <MySegment>
      <Field1>ABCDEF</Field1>
      <Field2>ABC</Field2>
    </MySegment>
  </ParentSegment>
</RecordsInp>
```

What I am getting is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <A>
      <Field1>Field1</Field1>
      <Field2>ABC</Field2>
    </A><A>
      <Field1>Field2</Field1>
      <Field2>A1</Field2>
    </A><A>
      <Field1>Field1</Field1>
      <Field2>ABCDEF</Field2>
    </A>
```

Notice I am not getting Field2=ABC in the last occurrence. Since Field2 never had ABC in previous occurrences, I need below XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A>
  <Field1>Field1</Field1>
  <Field2>ABC</Field2>
</A><A>
  <Field1>Field2</Field1>
  <Field2>A1</Field2>
</A><A>
  <Field1>Field1</Field1>
  <Field2>ABCDEF</Field2>
</A>
<A>
  <Field1>Field2</Field1>
  <Field2>ABC</Field2>
</A>
```

Comment: *"since ABCD123 contains ABCD as well,its being treated as a duplicate"* - No, not by the XPath you show.

Comment: Could you please advise how to correct this. My objective is to loop through all the fields of this segment and to populate them at header without any duplicates

Comment: We cannot advise you about how to correct your code without you explaining clearly exactly what your code is supposed to do, and presenting at least a characteristic example that demonstrates the erroneous behavior.  Together with example input and expected and observed output, we call this a [mcve], and it's what we expect you to provide in questions asking for help fixing your code.

Comment: Hi, I have added my issue in detail here. Kindly have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your second input example, the reason your stylesheet isn't pulling `<Field2>ABC</Field2>` the way you expect is because `ABC` exists as a value in a preceding `Field1`.

You *could* also test the name against the current (`current()`) name in the predicate, but maybe you should try using an `xsl:key` ([Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)) instead of the `preceding::` axis...

**XML Input**

```
<RecordsInp>
    <ParentSegment>
        <MySegment>
            <Field1>ABC</Field1>
            <Field2>A1</Field2>
        </MySegment>
        <MySegment>
            <Field1>ABC</Field1>
            <Field2>A1</Field2>
        </MySegment>
        <MySegment>
            <Field1>ABCDEF</Field1>
            <Field2>ABC</Field2>
        </MySegment>
    </ParentSegment>
</RecordsInp>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="fields" match="MySegment/*" 
    use="concat(name(),'|',normalize-space())"/>

  <xsl:template match="MySegment">
    <xsl:for-each 
      select="*[count(.|key('fields',concat(name(),'|',normalize-space()))[1])=1]">
      <A>
        <Field1><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></Field1>
        <Field2><xsl:value-of select="."/></Field2>
      </A>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<A>
   <Field1>Field1</Field1>
   <Field2>ABC</Field2>
</A>
<A>
   <Field1>Field2</Field1>
   <Field2>A1</Field2>
</A>
<A>
   <Field1>Field1</Field1>
   <Field2>ABCDEF</Field2>
</A>
<A>
   <Field1>Field2</Field1>
   <Field2>ABC</Field2>
</A>
```

Comment: The trick, of course, to applying Meunchian grouping to a problem such as this is to construct unambiguous key values.  When you need to form a key by concatenating multiple separate values, there is always a risk that you will be messed up by your chosen delimiter appearing in the data.  Obviously, that won't happen with this stylesheet and the OP's example data, but it's important to keep the possibility somewhere in the back of the mind.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - Very true. It's also good to note that instead of a single character delimiter, you can use any string. For example, instead of `|` I could've used `~StackOverflowIsAwesome~`.

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath expression `./MySegment/*[not(.=preceding::*)]` selects those child elements of each of the context node's `<MySegment>` children whose string values do not match those of *any* element preceding them in document order.  Thus, the `<Field2>ABC</Field2>` is not reflected in the result because of the preceding `<Field1>ABC</Field1>` elements.

Evidently that's a broader condition than you intend; as I understand it, you want to compare only with preceding elements having the same name.  That's a bit tricky to express in pure XPath; it would be easier to handle with a stylesheet refactoring.  Gratuitous use of `xsl:for-each` suggests such a refactoring anyway.  Here's a reasonable way to go about it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/RecordsInp/ParentSegment/MySegment/*">
    <!-- bind the context node's name and value to variables: -->
    <xsl:variable name="fname" select="name()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="fvalue" select="string(.)"/>

    <!-- here's the test you seem really to want: -->
    <xsl:if test="not(preceding::*[name() = $fname and string() = $fvalue])">
      <A>
        <Field1><xsl:value-of select ="$fname"/></Field1>
        <Field2><xsl:value-of select="$fvalue"/></Field2>
      </A>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```